# How to disable a spinner if Edit Text is empty in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I want to disable and reset a spinner if my Edit Text is Empty when I choose a spinner value

I tried..

```
if (position > 0) {

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(EditName.getText().toString())){
        EditName.setError("NAME IS EMPTY ");
        SpinNumbers.setSelection(0);
        SpinNumbers.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        SpinNumbers.setEnabled(true);
    }

}else{
    SpinNumbers.setEnabled(false);
}
```

What I m doing wrong here

Comment: Can you show me how are you adding value in your Spinner so that I can help you better

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ->

```
ediText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(count == 0){
            // Disable the spinner
            yourSpinner.setEnabled(false);
            yourSpinner.setClickable(false);
            yourSpinner.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
((Spinner) SpinNumbers).getSelectedView().setEnabled(false);
SpinNumbers.setEnabled(false);
```